# Deserialize JSON to Byte-Array in WebApi

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I am very new to Web API and I have troubles with deserialization of the following class:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual string Firstname { get; set; }
    public virtual string Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

When my UserController serialize the object to JSON and sends it back it looks like this in Fiddler:

```
{Username: "Foo", Firstname: Foo, Lastname: Bar,  RowVersion: "AAAAAAAAJxc=", Id: 8}
```

When the Client sends a PUT the RowVersion is the same in Fiddler but in my UserController's Put-method is a mistake. The object's RowVersion property has only 1 entry byte[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKM5L.png) = 0 instead of byte[8].

[image]

In fact of the different RowVersion, entity Framework throws an exception if I try to update the object (DBConcurrencyException).

So there must be an error when Web API deserialize the incoming JSON to create an object... Where can I solve my problem?

Thank you in advance!

Edit **SOLUTION**:

I've found a solution:

instead of

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(User usr)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I've changed it to:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
{
    var usr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonbody.Root.ToString());
    return Ok();

}
```

and now the byte[] (RowVersion) is correct. I don't know why it works this way but this could help people, too.

Comment: Are you updating the RowVersion or just sending back the same value?

Comment: I haven't updated the RowVersion. I've sent it back...

Comment: Your solution may be as simple as adding the `[Timestamp]` attribute to `RowVersion`. Alternatively, you could remove `RowVersion` if you aren't concerned about concurrency.

Comment: Can you change the type of RowVersion to 'string'?

Comment: Hey Brian, Entity Framework need the byte[] to save the concurrency (rowVersion) of the database

Comment: Have you set the content-type to `application/octet-stream` (binary) when calling the PUT method?

Comment: @JimAho I don't think that's necessary? http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @GrayFox I think you need to add the `[Timestamp]` attribute to the `RowVersion` field or configure it via the fluent API with `.IsConcurrencyToken()`. The link in my previous comment shows how.

Comment: Hey moarboilerplate, I have tried [Timestamp without any success ;(]